# Continuously check if class exists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using the below code to check if a class exists, and if so, show a button. However, the class can only exist after a user has done something on the page - so it will never exist on page load. How can I adjust this code to continuously check if the class exists, and not just on page load?

```js
if($(".acf-gallery-attachment").length()){
    return $('.acfef-submit-button').css("display", "block");
}
```

EDIT:

I've adjusted my code to look for when the user clicks the file upload button instead, but still cannot get it to work:

```
    $('.file-custom .acf-gallery-upload').click(function () {
        $('.acfef-submit-button').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

Comment: "the class can only exist after a user has done something on the page" - do your action when the user does their "something" don't poll externally for it having been done

Comment: See also: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: To be fair I've rigged up stuff like this so that (for example) when form inputs have been completed correctly, a "Proceed" button can be shown. It involves some non-trivial "wiring" between `<input>` elements and validation code.

Comment: @Pointy oh for sure, but there's often a much simpler alternative. Also note the existance of a `return` statement here - a strong hint that there's more to this than is being shown!

Comment: @Jamiec thanks for the recommendation. I've adjusted my code to see when the user clicks the file upload button, but still can't get it to work. No, there isn't more to my code. I just thought return was required.. I've removed that as well.

  $('.file-custom .acf-gallery-upload').click(function () {
   $('.acfef-submit-button').css('display', 'block');
  });

Comment: Original post updated for formatting on the above message

Comment: "Can't get it to work" does not help us answer your question unfortunately.  What happens? Do you get an error? does it do something other than you expect? Does it do nothing at all? have you tried debugging? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Inspect elements and check for typos.

Comment: Shot in the dark: if `.file-custom .acf-gallery-upload` is put on the page after page load use delegation `$(document).on("click",".file-custom .acf-gallery-upload", function() { ... });`

Comment: That was it.. Thank you so much, @Jameic.

Comment: Lucky guess, but note this was a true definition of the XY Problem! On your next question consider that and the how to ask page in the [help]

Comment: I will, thank you! Makes total sense. I should have considered a different set of logic to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is a good thing to do, but if you're looking to "continuously check" something, you could go with `setInterval`.

```js
setInterval(checkSomething, 1000);

function checkSomething(){
    if($(".acf-gallery-attachment").length()){
        return $('.acfef-submit-button').css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

Comment: note that the `return` won't do anything useful here. It hints that the OP has more code than is being shown.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! This will be useful to know in the future. I think I can adjust my code to look for a button click instead of continuously checking.

Answer (score 0):

how about a mutation observer?
set it to observe your container and its children for a change of class

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('container');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
       if( $('.myclass').length ){
         alert('my class is available');
       }else{
        alert(' my class not available');
       }  
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
  
  $('#btnAddClass').click(() =>{
    $('#myspan').addClass('myclass');
  })
  
  $('#btnRemoveClass').click(() =>{
    $('#myspan').removeClass('myclass');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "container">
    <span id="myspan"></span>
    <button id="btnAddClass">
      add class
    </button>
     <button id="btnRemoveClass">
      remove class
    </button>
</div>
```